# If $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, is it true that $f(\text{Int}(A))=\text{Int}(f(A))$ for each subset $A$ of $X$?

Tags: general-topology

We define the [*interior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)) $\text{Int}(A)$ of a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ to be the set of all $x\in X$ such that $x\in U\subseteq A$ for some $U$ open in $X$.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ be a homeomorphism. Is it true that for each subset $A$ of $X$, we have that $f(\text{Int}(A))=\text{Int}(f(A))$?

**Edit:** I know that if $f$ is an open map, then $f(\text{int}A)\subseteq\text{int}(f(A))$,  but what about the other side?
Any help please.

Comment: Continuity of $f$ yields that $f^{-1}(\operatorname{Int}(B)) \subseteq \operatorname{Int}(f^{-1}(B))$ for any $B \subseteq Y$. What happens if $B=f(A)$?

Comment: it will be f−1 (Int(f(A))) ⊆ Int (A) ,, but i dont understand what you mean

Comment: Right, and taking $f$ on both sides of the inclusion $f^{-1}(\operatorname{Int}(f(A))) \subseteq \operatorname{Int}(A)$ we get that...

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subseteq X$ and $y\in Y$. If $y\in f(\text{Int}(A))$, then $y=f(x)$ and for some $x\in\text{Int}(A)$. Then $x\in U\subseteq A$ for some $U$ open in $X$ and so $f(x)\in f(U)\subseteq f(A)$ implies that $y\in\text{Int}(f(A))$.

On the other hand, if $y\in\text{Int}(f(A))$, then $y\in V\subseteq f(A)$ for some $V$ open in $Y$. Then $f^{-1}(y)\in f^{-1}(V)\subseteq A$ gives that $f^{-1}(y)\in\text{Int}(A)$ and therefore $y\in f(\text{Int}(A))$.